# An error in the running of kotline in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0nnp.jpg)

Can anyone say how to debug it

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, try to be more specific with the error message. I mean copy&paste the error in the question in order to be more clear. Just a suggestion by the error message is that you are using wrong command. What are you trying to do exactly by this command?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your *kotlin* directory is not added to your *PATH* variable thus the extension/terminal may not know what to execute, when trying to execute `kotlinc`.

---

The easiest way to resolve this issue is by adding the path to your kotlin directory (`path/to/your/kotlin/bin`) to your *PATH* variable
(see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-a-directory-to-the-path-environment-variable-in-windows#answer-9546345)), if you are on windows, or [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path#answer-26059), if you are on a linux system.

You can check, if it works by opening a command line window and trying to execute
`kotlinc -version`

---

However, as it seems like you are using [Code-Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension in vscode, you can also update your *settings.json* file:
[reference here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner#configuration).

Comment: Unfortunately, it is very hard to help you, if you do not specify your problem. Have you tried running `kotlinc --version`?